# how to get/set the salt for a JdbcRealm

Tags: java, shiro, salt, jdbcrealm

I am attempting to use the Shiro JdbcRealm and SHA256 hashedcredentialsMatcher.   I need to update a legacy database and assign the appropriate salt for each user (via a batch routine).

how do I get/set the salt for a given account using the Shiro framework?

Answer (score 8):

With Shiro 1.2.3 all you need to do is:

1. **Extend `JdbcRealm`** and set salt style.

   ```java
   public class JdbcSaltRealm extends JdbcRealm {
       public JdbcSaltRealm() {
           setSaltStyle(SaltStyle.COLUMN);
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Update `shiro.ini`** to use extended realm and to get salt column from DB

   ```conf
   credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
   credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
   jdbcRealm = com.mypackage.JdbcSaltRealm
   jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt FROM user WHERE username = ?
   jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
   ```
3. **Hash & salt current / new user passwords.** This should be done for all existing users as well as on new user registrations.

   ```java
   private void saltHashPassword(String password) {

       String salt = new BigInteger(250, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);

       //TODO: save salt value to "salt" column in user table

       Sha256Hash hash = new Sha256Hash(password, 
                             (new SimpleByteSource(salt)).getBytes());
       String saltedHashedPassword = hash.toHex();

       //TODO: save saltedHashedPassword value to "password" column in user table
   }
   ```

I hope my answer is clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late:

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.de/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html).
Meri, the guy who owns the blog, describes exactly how to create an own **salted JDBC Realm**.

This is also an acknowledged [improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-277) in the community for version 1.3.0 .

Hope this helpes, have Fun!